# How to install bazel4.2 on OpenSuse

Tags: opensuse

It seems OpenSuse provide `bazel4.2` package, unfortunately it is an experimental/community package and I don't know how to enable this feed in my opensuse based Dockerfile.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM opensuse/tumbleweed
RUN zypper update -y \
&& zypper install -y bazel4.2

RUN bazel --version
```

### Observed

```sh
docker build --tag=plop .
...
Retrieving repository 'openSUSE-Tumbleweed-Non-Oss' metadata [..done]
Building repository 'openSUSE-Tumbleweed-Non-Oss' cache [....done]
Retrieving repository 'openSUSE-Tumbleweed-Oss' metadata [......done]
Building repository 'openSUSE-Tumbleweed-Oss' cache [....done]
Retrieving repository 'openSUSE-Tumbleweed-Update' metadata [.done]
Building repository 'openSUSE-Tumbleweed-Update' cache [....done]
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
Nothing to do.
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
No provider of 'bazel4.2' found.
'bazel4.2' not found in package names. Trying capabilities.
```

### Expected

Bazel4.2 is retrieved and installed from one community/experimental repository.

ref: https://software.opensuse.org/package/bazel4.2

Answer (score 1):

after few trial and error

Dockerfile:

```
FROM opensuse/tumbleweed
RUN zypper update -y
# https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Add_package_repositories
RUN zypper ar -Gf https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:tools:building/openSUSE_Factory/devel:tools:building.repo
# https://software.opensuse.org/package/bazel4.2
RUN zypper install -y bazel4.2

RUN bazel --version
```